# Exception while submitting spark application in yarn mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

**Exception :**
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/util/List;

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code and/or commands. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. We can't really say anything meaningful about just an error. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the [edit] button to update your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is case of library versions collisions. You should check few things: what is your runtime classpath, especially check libraries from hadoop instalation. What libraries you bring with your fat-jar if any. What libraries you add with --jar option. You also should check what libraries spark  depends on. Everything should be consistent, but your error hints that you built your app jar with 1 version but in runtime there is another version